# How to add word tags in to JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, swingx

I am creating Java Swing application. I want to add tags to `JTextField`.  When I add tag I can search another tag to add.  Same like stack overflow.

Is there any jar files to do that? Please tell me if there any other solutions.

[example image tag http://imageshack.com/a/img674/925/kQRLxw.jpg](http://imageshack.com/a/img674/925/kQRLxw.jpg)

Comment: I'd use a JPanel that holds JButtons, not a JTextField for this sort of thiing.

Comment: ok thanx how do you add that close button and search another tag using jtextfield?

Comment: panel with 2 labels one for text other one for close button

Comment: @Heshan jayasinghe A Swing component (JComponent) is a direct subclass of Container. Therefore, you can add a any JComponent to another JComponent using its `add()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically you need to add 2 `jlables` in to one panel and then add that panel to another panel.

i created a custom panel named "`Tagpanel`" and add new TagPanel to panel .

This is how it looks .you should use appropriate layout to your case.

[image]

example code

```
public class Example extends JFrame {

    static Example example;
    JPanel panel;

    String tagarr[] = {"swing", "java", "c++", "awt"};

    public Example() {
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 80));
        GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(layout);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;

        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 20));
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(1, 2, 2));
        panel.setBackground(Color.white);
        panel.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.magenta));
        add(panel,c);
        JTextField t = new JTextField("type here", 10);
        t.setBorder(null);
        t.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                tagcheck(evt);
            }

            private void tagcheck(KeyEvent evt) {
                String s = t.getText();
                if (s.length() > 0) {
                    for (String tag : tagarr) {
                        if (s.equals(tag)) {
                            TagPanel tagp1 = new TagPanel(s);
                            panel.add(tagp1, panel.getComponentCount() - 1);
                            t.setText("");
                            repaint();
                            revalidate();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        panel.add(t);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void removecomp(JPanel p) {
        panel.remove(p);
        repaint();
        revalidate();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        example = new Example();
    }
}
```

TagPanel.java

```
public class TagPanel extends JPanel {

    public TagPanel(String text) {
        JLabel textlable = new JLabel(text);
        JLabel close = new JLabel("X");
        close.setOpaque(true);
        close.setBackground(new Color(123, 123, 123));
        textlable.setOpaque(true);
        textlable.setBackground(new Color(0,185,203));
        textlable.setForeground(Color.white);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        close.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                Example.example.removecomp(TagPanel.this);
            }
        });
        add(close, BorderLayout.EAST);
        add(textlable, BorderLayout.WEST);
    }

}
```